# How to use Interface on Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

In my application i want **implement** some `interface` into `fragment`!
When use this `interface` i write this for add `listeners`, but show me error and not allow me for use this!
**I write below codes into fragment :**

```
public class ServicesFragment extends Fragment implements IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_services, container, false);

    public class LoginCheckServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder boundService) {
            service = ILoginCheckService.Stub.asInterface((IBinder) boundService);
            try {
                boolean isLoggedIn = service.isLoggedIn();
                if (isLoggedIn) {
                    iabHelper = new IabHelper(context, bazaarRSA);
                    iabHelper.startSetup(this);
                } else {
                    if (Constants.isPackageInstalled(Constants.BAZAAR_PAYMENT_PACKAGE, packageManager)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(Constants.BAZAAR_PAYMENT_PACKAGE, Constants.BAZAAR_LOGIN_ACTIVITY));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Not installed market on your device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            service = null;
        }
    }
}
```

In this code : `iabHelper.startSetup(this);` when use `this` show me error!

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `startSetup` signature is .

```
public void startSetup(final OnIabSetupFinishedListener listener)
```

Problem:- You are passing `this` which will give the reference of immediate parent class which is `LoginCheckServiceConnection` in this case.

Solution:- Use `ClassName.this` to get outer class reference cause your outer class already implementing `OnIabSetupFinishedListener`.

```
iabHelper.startSetup(ServicesFragment.this);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you initialize this inside the `onCreateView()` or no nested codes then `iabHelper.startSetup(this)` can implicitly serves your context as usual. Also the reference of immediate parent class which is `LoginCheckServiceConnection` in this case.

But if you deep drive into nested code then only `this` can not serves implicitly your context as usual.
For that you can explicitly write that `iabHelper.startSetup(ServicesFragment.this);`